# Как поддерживать SSH тунель активным

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Есть компьютер с `ubuntu 16` у которого серый `IP`, и есть `vps` - хочу как-то держать постоянно активным `ssh тунель` от `vps` до компьютера.

Сейчас, для простоты персонала, на компьютере `bash` скрипт который который создает туннель от себя до сервера, но для его запуска нужно что-бы кто-то запустил скрипт. Можно поставить в автозапуск скрипт, но если пропадет интернет, то и соединение прервется.

Можно в теории написать срипт, который будет раз в минуту смотреть активные соединения, и если `ssh` не будет то скрипт будет перезапускать скрипт, который создает тунель. Или как правильно сделать так что бы было активное соединение по ssh с `vps`, и чтобы если соединение прервано, то создавалась занова?

Может есть кикие-то готовые решения? Программы по типу `AnyDesk` не подходят, из-за того что я буду забирать у персонала управление над компьютером.

Comment: ServerAliveInterval  в .ssh/config

Comment: autossh: https://www.opennet.ru/tips/2157_ssh_tunnel_ping.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С опцией ServerAliveInterval=5 клиент будет посылать каждые 5 секунд сообщения поддержания сессии, и если сообщение не доходит, то сессия обрывается сразу.

Скрипт запуска приведи к виду, например:

```
while true
do
  ssh 203.0.113.2 -l root -N -R 0.0.0.0:0:127.0.0.1:22 -o ServerAliveInterval=5
done
```

При обрыве связи ssh будет обрываться и переподключаться в вечном цикле

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек.

Для устойчивой работы через соединение SSH можно использовать [mosh](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)).

Mosh — программа для удалённого подключения с клиентского компьютера к серверу через Интернет. Предоставляет доступ к текстовому терминалу. Mosh аналогичен приложению SSH, но имеет дополнительные функции, предназначенные для повышения удобства работы мобильных пользователей.

Основные задачи, которые решает mosh:

- Возможность роуминга ssh-соединений. Переключайтесь между wi-fi
  сетями, не бойтесь смены IP в мобильных сетях — соединение не
  разорвется. От себя замечу, можно закрыть ноутбук на работе и открыть уже дома, vim открыт с курсором в том же месте, где вы делали последнее редактирование, как будто соединение не пропадало вовсе.
- Уменьшение лагов насколько это возможно, за счет использования UDP и
  умного predictive echo.
- Оптимизация использования сети — протокол mosh позволяет передавать только то, что должно быть отображено. В итоге Сtrl-C работает мгновенно, даже если вы выплюнули в консоль содержимое 500GB файла.
- Максимальная обратная совместимость — от  пользователя требуется минимум телодвижений и знаний, чтобы начать использовать mosh.

Как правило, remote-shell протоколы исповедуют подход «сервер отправляет все данные клиенту, а клиент уже разбирается, как их отображать». Mosh идет другим путем и хранит состояние экрана на клиенте и сервере, и эти два состояния постоянно синхронизирует — собственно, протокол так и называется — State Synchronization Protocol. Протокол позволяет контролировать частоту синхронизации, в зависимости от качества сетевого соединения.

[Источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/243651/)